# Date comparisson issue MS ACCESS 2007

Tags: date, ms-access

I have been reading and learning a lot on this site, and now its my time to set a question, which is giving me some problems.

I have a query on MS ACCESS on which i need to compare two different dates, call them CreationDate and AnalysisDate. I compare them in order to get results for two different criterias:

Crit1:

```
SiInm(CreationDate < AnalysisDate;1)
```

Crit2:

```
SiInm(CreationDate >= AnalysisDate;1)
```

I have had no problems comparing dates within June, but when i try to compare dates from June as > or < with July, and it returns a wrong result.

Does anybody knows why this happen?

I checked on my tables and the date format is well setted on every source table i use on my queries.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Regards

PS: SiInm works as IF (function in Spanish)

Comment: The date fields are date/time type? Using U.S. format, not international? Edit question to include the full query SQL statement and sample data.

Comment: Hi June. Yes, date fields are all date/time type, i checked them.

How do i check if im using one format or another?

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: is it mysql or ms-access?

Answer (score 0):

> PS: SiInm works as IF (function in Spanish)

It most likely doesn't. If it can't compare date values, it's because it converts internally to string expressions which can't be compared reliably.

You don't tell what SiInm does. Perhaps it strips a time part.

So, either correct SiInm or use:

```
CreationDate < AnalysisDate
```

or:

```
DateValue(CreationDate) < DateValue(AnalysisDate)
```

or use *DateDiff* which is here exactly for comparing date values:

```
DateDiff("d"; CreationDate; AnalysisDate) > 0
```

Comment: I understand your point, but i need to call another field to be shown considering the result of the SiInm evaluation.
I will try using DateValue within SiInm loop and will post my result.